# how to set MAPE cost function in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement MAPE(Mean Absolute Percentage Error) in tensorflow. I'm taking output from the RNN.

Here is my code :

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.divide(tf.subtract(outputs,y),y)))
```

But on running the session I'm getting MAPE as NaN. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check if you have `Nan`s in your `outputs` or `y`, or `0`s (or very small values) in `y`  (even one of these is enough)

Comment: @gdelab It is `Nan` in the output

Comment: I mean in your tensor named `outputs`, the one inside `(tf.subtract(outputs,y)`

Comment: @gdelab How to check it ?

Comment: You can use [`outputs=tf.check_numerics(tensor=outputs, message="outputs has a strange value")`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/check_numerics) and `y=tf.check_numerics(tensor=y, message="y has a strange value")` before creating your loss, and `minimum_y=tf.reduce_min(tf.abs(y))` where you want, and just also run `minimum_y` in your `sess.run()` and see if check_numerics outputs any message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect you are getting NaN because y is zero.  To get around this you can add a very small epsilon value to y denominator to ensure it's never zero, but small enough not to skew your calculations:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.divide(tf.subtract(outputs,y),(y + 1e-10))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You get nan because y includes a zero value. Therefore it is impossible tensorflow to produce the division as a result it outputs inf.